# How do I search for a list of strings with find and grep

Tags: bash, scripting, zsh

I am trying to make the following into a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /path/to/file -type f -name "*.html" -exec grep -l "XXXX" '{}' \; -print
```

where XXXX is a list of strings over which this command should be looped. I struggle to make the correct portion of this script into a loop and I struggle to save the XXXX to a variable that will then be looped over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the `zsh` tag but have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang. `bash` and `zsh` are two different shells.

One way to have `grep` look for a number of strings is to call it with `grep -F -e 'first string' -e 'second string' -e'blah'...`.

In zsh, if you have the list of strings in an array:

```
strings=('first string' 'second string' '***')
```

You can do:

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Frl --include='*.html' -e$^strings .
```

Or using `find`:

```
find . -name '*.html' -type f -exec grep -Fl -e$^strings {} +
```

Or using `zsh`'s recursive globbing and glob qualifiers:

```
grep -Fl -e$^strings -- **/*.html(D.)
```

Or to work around the system's limit on the number of arguments you can pass to a command like `find`'s `-exec` does, in case there are many html files:

```
autoload -Uz zargs
zargs -- **/*.html(D.) -- grep -Fl -e$^strings --
```

That also has the advantage of sorting the list of files (you can disable that sorting by adding the `oN` glob qualifier to `N`ot `o`rder).

Note that `-l` is already to print (list) the filenames that contain at least one match, adding `-print`, so the filename be printed when `grep` succeeds is redundant and would meant the file names are printed twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to `grep` for any of the strings represented by XXXX in every .html file in that directory and return the files where any of the strings appear, then the following will be sufficient:

```
egrep -l "string1|string2|string3" /path/to/directory/*.html 

grep -El "string1|string2|string3" /path/to/directory/*.html
```

They both do the same but one uses `egrep` instead of `grep -E`. The `-l` switch returns the file that the string appears in and not the line containing it. If you really need to assign the strings to a variable:

```
export strings='string1|string2|string3'

egrep -l "$strings" /path/to/directory/*.html 

grep -El "strings" /path/to/directory/*.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file with the strings you want to look for:

file.txt

```
foo
bar
```

And then

```
find /path/to/file -type f -name "*.html" -exec grep -l -f file.txt '{}' \; -print
```

Answer (score -1):

I you want to perform any operation on the files where strings are available use the below:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a STRINGS=$(find /var/www/html/ -type f -name "*.html" -exec grep "this is 
test" {} \; -print)

for string in "${STRINGS[@]}"
do
   echo "${string}"
    echo "${STRINGS}"

done
```

O/P:

```
[root@awx html]# sh test.sh
this is test file1
/var/www/html/1.html
this is test file2
/var/www/html/2.html
this is test file1
/var/www/html/1.html
this is test file2
/var/www/html/2.html
[root@awx html]#
```